# Get incremental changes for a group in Microsoft Graph in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to get users from an AAD group:

```
public async Task<IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage> GetGroupMembersPageByIdAsync(string groupId)
{   
        return await graphServiceClient
                        .Groups[groupId]
                        .TransitiveMembers
                        .Request()
                        .Top(999)
                        .GetAsync();    
}


public async Task<IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage> GetGroupMembersNextPageAsnyc(
    IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage groupMembersRef,
    string nextPageUrl)
{   
        groupMembersRef.InitializeNextPageRequest(_graphServiceClient, nextPageUrl);
        return await groupMembersRef
                        .NextPageRequest
                        .GetAsync();    
}

public async Task<(List<AzureADUser> users,                
                   string nextPageUrl,
                   IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)> GetFirstUsersPageAsync(Guid objectId)
{
    var users = new List<AzureADUser>();
    var usersFromGroup = await GetGroupMembersPageByIdAsync(objectId.ToString());   
    usersFromGroup.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink", out object nextLink1);
    var nextPageUrl = (nextLink1 == null) ? string.Empty : nextLink1.ToString();
    users.AddRange((IEnumerable<AzureADUser>)(usersFromGroup));
    return (users,  nextPageUrl, usersFromGroup);
}

public async Task<(List<AzureADUser> users,                
                   string nextPageUrl,
                   IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)> GetNextUsersPageAsync(string nextPageUrl, IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)
{
    var users = new List<AzureADUser>();    
    usersFromGroup = await GetGroupMembersNextPageAsnyc(usersFromGroup, nextPageUrl);   
    usersFromGroup.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink", out object nextLink2);
    nextPageUrl = (nextLink2 == null) ? string.Empty : nextLink2.ToString();
    users.AddRange((IEnumerable<AzureADUser>)(usersFromGroup));
    return (users, nextPageUrl, usersFromGroup);
}
```

I'm trying to learn about how I can use delta query functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups so that next time when I run this, I can get the difference (new users/removed users/updated users) and return that list. Is that possible via delta query functionality?

Comment: Any other questions on this question?

Comment: Yes how do I collect users and store in a list from delta query in C#?

Comment: I've post my idea in your another question, pls check it. And on this case, it seems that you don't  have any other question. You can create new question if you still have other concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a test in my asp.net core mvc project and you can get delta information by code below.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    //get group members
    var users = await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].TransitiveMembers.Request().Top(999).GetAsync();
    //get group member delta info
    var delta = await graphClient.Groups.Delta().Request().Filter("id eq 'group_id'").GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain what this indicates? var delta = await graphClient.Groups.Delta().Request().Filter("id eq 'group_id'").GetAsync();

Comment: Here's the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-1) about how to use delta query to query group update information. The response will also include group member updating information. But if we didn't add a filter, it will return all groups update information, so when we add a filter to let the api only return data related to the specfic group, then it is.

Comment: About the `filter`, it's from Odata which is supported by ms graph api.

Comment: Can I use .Top(999) in the delta query to return 999 members per page?

Comment: @user989988  About the `Top(999)`, the api document doesn't mention if it can support, so you may try to test it in yourself.

Comment: Can you please answer this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823061/get-users-from-aad-group-using-graph-api-using-delta-query